xdotool fails to set terminal profile on Ubuntu 22.04
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.
I have three profiles in my terminal, a default builtin and two I made myself :

My "OCaml" profile has a blue background color among other things :

But when I try to use xdotool as suggested in the answers from this older question to set my profile programmatically, none of them work :
the background color stays unchanged.

Any ideas ?
Update: Just to be clear, I'm not looking for a way to set my default profile to "OCaml", I want to leave the default as it is, and only use my Ocaml profile when you guessed it, I'm progaramming in the OCaml language. The reason I want to do it programmatically, using the command line, is that as of now, when I start programming in OCaml in my terminal I do two separate things : calling a bash script to setup my OCaml environment and setting the profile to OCaml using the Gnome GUI. I would like to merge those two actions into one to save time.

Do you even need xdotool to do this? gnome-terminal I'm pretty sure allows you to set a default profile, and it has a --profile option which allows you to start a terminal with a selected profile for automation. May I ask why you want to do this using xdotool ? Perhaps there's a better way.

@kos I want to do it using the command-line, using xdotool or any other command-line tool, see the update in my question. I mentioned xdotool only because it was mentioned in the older answers I found

What does your script do? If your script involves, among other things, starting the terminal, you could just put gnome-terminal --profile=OCaml in the script so that the gnome-terminal instance spawned by the script would use the Ocaml profile, without changing the default profile (i.e. launching it e.g. via CTRL+ALT+T would still load the default profile)

@kos My script cd's into a sepcific directory and launches the OCaml interpreter. But I don't know how to tell the terminal to do those things in the freshly opened terminal. gnome-terminal --profile==OCaml && ... doesn't work.

You have one too many = in the command, it should be gnome-terminal --profile=OCaml (this works for me). Can you post the whole script? So that we can see how to incorporate this into it?

@kos I've reread-it, and it's actually simple enough to be put into a one-line command without need to put it into a script. The exact content is
cd $CAML_DIR && codium . && dune utop lib. The obvious, natural thing to do would then be gnome-terminal --profile=OCaml && cd $CAML_DIR && codium . && dune utop lib
Unfortunately, all the commands after the first && are executed in the first terminal, not the freshly created one.

You could run gnome-terminal --profile=OCaml -- sh -c "cd $CAML_DIR && codium . && dune utop lib; exec bash". If I understood everything correctly. Otherwise please explain what the last dune command does. If it's a GUI application taking over the terminal, you can background / detach its process with nohup: gnome-terminal --profile=OCaml -- sh -c "cd $CAML_DIR && codium . && nohup dune utop lib >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown; exec bash"

@kos Your first proposal worked fine for me, thx a lot. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it

You're welcome! I added a variation using exit in case it's desirable to close the first terminal after the fact, and a note on how you could automate the whole thing by using a .desktop file.

There's no need to use xdotool in this case, as gnome-terminal accepts a --profile parameter which will make it spawn a terminal instance with a transient profile.
Furthermore, if you signal it the end of the arguments list using --, gnome-terminal will execute the remainder of the command line.
As explained in the comments you need to setup your environment by running cd $CAML_DIR && codium . && dune utop lib. Putting everything toghether:
gnome-terminal --profile=OCaml -- sh -c "cd $CAML_DIR && codium . && dune utop lib; exec bash"

The exec bash bit at the end is what forces the terminal to stay open after the other commands have been executed. If you want to close the original terminal after the fact, you can simply chain exit to the command above:
gnome-terminal --profile=OCaml -- sh -c "cd $CAML_DIR && codium . && dune utop lib; exec bash"; exit

You could also look into putting the first command into a .desktop file; that way you could have a convenient double-click method of setting up the whole thing without having to spawn (and close) a terminal instance just to set up the environment.
